# What are the alternate technologies for Rule engines?

Tags: rule-engine

Rule Engine is generally for automatically and dynamically executing a set of  rules to arrive at a result. Rule engine is more specifically useful to separate business component from the technology manipulations. Can any other technology be an alternate for rule engine but still perform the same automation on dynamic information?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Are you asking if there are other technologies out there that are capable of separating business components from technology and universally evaluate conditions and execute steps? If so, how far can we go in the answer? I would argue that XML and Neural Nets can also fit these requirements but not sure what you are looking for. Please elaborate

Comment: What problem(s) are you trying to solve? You should be more specific about the problem when you want to talk about alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [NebriOS](http://nebrios.com)? I would be surprised if that didn't meet your needs. It sounds like you might be looking for a more generic solution that an Business Rule Management environment that can interact with other platforms and services. Maybe, more of a standalone software tool?